# Generate statistics for every column in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to generate statistics for every column in a table. There are multiple sets of data in the table which can be queried by using the `token` field. The statistics I want to compile for now are simple: max, min, and average.

I know how to do this with a very brute force query, but I'm looking for something more elegant. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    MAX(`A`),
    MIN(`A`),
    AVG(`A`)
FROM `table`
WHERE ...
```

That works, but I have to know all of the fields ahead of time, which makes the query really unwieldy. Also, it returns a single row of data when what I really want is a row per field with the max, min, and average per field.

```
Field    Max    Min    Avg
A        4      1      2
B        10     8      9
C        12     1      3
```

I know I need a query that's the functional equivalent of a for loop over the field list, but that's currently beyond my MySQL abilities. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My question is similar to this one: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349108/mysql-query-for-max-of-all-columns). One of the comments essentially asked for the same thing I'm suggesting - a way to run this type of query over one or more tables without knowing the number of fields ahead of time. I realize I can run a query to `describe` the table and the loop over the results, but that feels too manual. Maybe that's the best way, but I thought I should ask in case I can learn a better way.

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL to solve this problem -- which is essentially using `describe` and then looping over the results.  There are ways to make this code work with no manual intervention, but it is still code rather than a single query.

Comment: I don't have any idea what you're talking about Strawberry. I know what normalization means, but not how it applies here. I don't need to alter the data in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing there's a better way to do this, but I solved my problem with the following code. I thought I should post it here in case it helps others.

```
<?php
require_once("dbconfig.php");
$con = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
mysql_select_db($db);

$tokens = explode(",", $_GET['tokens']);
$test   = $_GET['test'];

$sql  = "DESCRIBE `{$test}`";
$rows = mysql_query($sql);
$fields = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rows)) {
    $fields[] = $row[0];
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>\n");
echo "<rows>";

foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $sql = "SELECT MAX(`{$field}`),MIN(`{$field}`),AVG(`{$field}`)
            FROM `{$test}` WHERE token = " . implode(" OR token = ", $tokens);

    $rows = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rows)) {
        echo "<row id='{$field}'>";
        echo "<cell>{$field}</cell>";
        for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
            echo "<cell>" . number_format($row[$i],3)  . "</cell>";
        }
        echo "</row>";
    }
}

echo "</rows>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a dynamic query, there seems to be no other option but this one

```
SELECT "A" `Column`, MAX(A) `Min`, MIN(A) `Max`, AVG(A) `Avg` FROM `table`
UNION
SELECT "B" `Column`, MAX(B) `Min`, MIN(B) `Max`, AVG(B) `Avg` FROM `table`
UNION
SELECT "C" `Column`, MAX(C) `Min`, MIN(C) `Max`, AVG(C) `Avg` FROM `table`
```

Resulting in a statistic for each column, eg.

```
Column  Min     Max     Avg
A       8       1       1.0360
B       127     1       3.9095
C       7       12      2.152
```